# How to obtain all directories from a path efficiently

Tags: vimscript

Of course I can just do

```
let dir = globpath('path', '*', 0, 1)
for file in dir
   if (isdirectory(file))
       add(myDirList, file)
   endif
endfor
```

But this will have to go through all the files in the directory and when the list is large this can take quite a long time. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

**Edit:** Response to @Luc Hermitte

Testing `globpath()` and `for` loop together: 66.73 seconds.

Testing `globpath()` and `filter` together: 64.11 seconds.

A couple things to note about my specific situation.

- I'm trying to access a network drive.
- My first tests where done on wifi. I've connected with a hard wire and times have been reduced by about 25%.
- The directory I'm accessing has ~2500 files/directories on it.

I've now tested the individual times on a hard wire connection and got the following times:

- `globpath()`: 40.19 seconds
- `for` loop: 4.96 seconds
- `filter`: 4.91 seconds
- `system('dir "path"')`: 0.17 seconds...  (I'm on Windows obviously)

Not sure why `for` and `filter` are so close when I got better results with `filter` before...

So yeah, the external is magnitudes faster. You think this deserves a bug report?

P.S. I used `globpath()` because I didn't want to `cd` to the directory, but now I know that's not necessary.

Comment: Are external commands (e.g. `find`) an option?

Comment: I'd prefer a native solution, but I could work with external.

Answer (score 3):

`:for` loops are a performance nightmare.

Always prefer `map()` and `filter()` when you can.

Here, it would be:

```
let dir = globpath('path', '*', 0, 1)
call filter(dir, 'isdirectory(v:val)')
```

Comment: Sorry I meant to respond to this earlier, but things got a little crazy. Thanks for this. I'll definitely keep this in mind in the future. However for my particular case, the for isn't the biggest problem. Using a for took 66.73 seconds and using a  filter took 64.11 seconds. An improvement yes, but it also shows that the biggest problem is the glob. Any alternative to a glob, or is it just moving to external commands to get that time down?

Comment: Don't worry. I'm quite surprised though that `globpath()` takes that much time for files in a single directory, compared to `filter()`. How many files are there in your directory? Or may be you're using `**/*`? How much time the equivalent (untested) `echo "${paths[@]}" |xargs -L1 -I {} find {} -type d` takes? If the simple `globpath('path', '*', 0, 1)` is that slow comparatively, it deserves a bug report IMO.
BTW, if you have only one path, you could use `glob()` instead of `globpath()`

Comment: Also, you should measure the time spent by `globpath()` itself, and the one took in `filter()` -- in case the real culprit is `isdirectory()`.

Comment: Yeah, I think `isdirectory()` can be expansive. How about `globpath('dir', '*/', 0, 1)`?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I thought of trying `globpath('dir', '*/', 0, 1)` but it still returns all files as well.

Comment: On an UNIX box, I've just tested that `echo glob(dir.'/*/')` doesn't return files. BTW, what about the old DOS trick? `dir *.` only returns directories.  Of course, it'll only speed-up the fastest operation of the two, not the problematic one: `glob*()`